# Tracking Careers' shared invitation acceptance

Tags: feature-request, support, status-bydesign, jobs

How can I say which friends of mine have accepted or not invitations sent via Careers 2.0?

The invitations page just shows when and if they were accepted, but not whom.

```
Previously sent invitations

Sent to     Sent            Accepted?   Published?
via share   Sep 18, 2012    Yes         Yes
via share   Sep 12, 2012    Yes         No
via share   Sep 12, 2012    Yes         No
```

I'd like to visualize my peers along the system.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant "shared invitations"? Because for personal invitations the contact details do appear under "sent to".

Comment: Yes, they were sent to a group of e-mails, greater than the number of invitations acquired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a person accepts your invitation via a share, and makes their profile public, the “Yes” under “Published?” will be linked to their public profile. If not, we can’t reveal any information about the profile or contact information.

Comment: no link available for me, although one of my peers has published its profile.

It's kind of frustrating not being able to visualize my friendship network after bringing them into the platform. The 'shared link' invitation method should have a **big** disclaimer warning about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

These are invitations used by a share link.  If you actually specify the email address to send an invitation to, you can see the email address you sent it to (not necessarily the one they used for the account) under the Sent To heading.

Comment: I had no clue about this limitation on using shared links. However, it'd be nice to track their acceptance anyway.