# How can I see my invitee's Career Profile?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've invited 2 folks to SO Careers (which I use as a candidate).  I'd like to check out my invitees' profiles so that I can I offer them advice getting it set up, and send out links to their profiles when I see an appropriate opening.

How can I see / share invitees' profiles?

(SO may not be a *social* network, but career searching is inherently social.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see their profile if it is public.

If they did not make it public, you cannot see it.

Comment: The invites list as Accepted and Published.  But how do I even find them?  The are no links under Invites.

Comment: @KatieK they have to share thier public link with you ^_^ [like me](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/naftali)

Comment: There's no way to search for candidates by name or email?

Comment: @KatieK not unless you are a recruiter -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Answer (score 1):

If the user makes their profile public, the "Yes" text under "Published?" will be [a link to their public profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148347).

If the "Yes" isn't a link, you'll have to wait until they make their profile public to see what they're doing.